# using a drop down menu to run mysql queries

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm currently using onclick actions to run mysql queries located on other web pages within my domain.  Those queries are then displayed in an iframe on the page where the onclick occured.  The code works as is but I've been wondering if there's a way to run them through a drop down menu.  I don't need help building the menu.  I think it'll give me a little more flexibility but I Haven't come across any good example of how to d it.  I don't want anyone to write my code for me, but I would appreciate it if I could get steered towards a good tutorial or other resource.  I've included my code here just in case it's helpful pointing me towards a solution.

```
<div class="center">
<p>
 <button onclick="myFunction1()">Illustrators</button>
 <button onclick="myFunction2()">Tech Writers</button>
 </p>
</div>

<script>
var iframeExists = false;

 function myFunction1() {
 var x
 if (!iframeExists) {
  x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframeExists = true;
 } else {
  x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
 }
 x.setAttribute ("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Illustrators.php");
 document.body.appendChild(x);
 }

function myFunction2() {
var x;
if (!iframeExists) {
  x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframeExists = true;
} else {
  x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
}
x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/TechWriters.php");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try jquery using select change event.

```
$("#dropdownID").change(function(){
    if(yourcondition){
       //run query or call query in another function
    }else{
       //run query or call query in another function
    }
});
```

Comment: so where woud I place this then?  I already have separate functions for each button, i.e. function myFunction1() , function myFunction2() , etc.

Comment: you can add this script on your page inside a <script></script> tags but make sure that the document is ready before you call it

Comment: right now the onclick event triggers the my sql which is loaded on a separate page within my domain and then called into the iframe so that's not a problem.  I have each function currently set up to use the same iframe.  I'm already running if/else for each function to use the iframe.  I'm not sure how to set your recommendations up by just replacing what I have with it.